# Fix DNS leak (from VyprVPN's CLI)

Tags: dns, vpn

I'm using [VyprVPN's CLI](https://support.goldenfrog.com/hc/en-us/articles/204102996-VyprVPN-CLI-for-Linux), connected to a server overseas. But my DNS is leaking (I used [this site](https://ipleak.net/) to check).

I've found several answers for this question, but there were all for the manual configuration of OpenVPN—not using VyprVPN's CLI.

I've tried to figure it out but I'm not sure how the CLI works, or even where to find the configuration files for it. I've contacted customer support, too, but they wouldn't offer any help other than linking me to where I can download their `.ovpn` configuration files.

How can I configure my VPN / network connection to stop leaking my DNS?

#### Other details

**OS:** Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Have you tried Golden Frog Support?

Comment: @OrganicMarble yep, I mentioned that (unless you're referring to something else)